Can I apply a different sub schema based on the value of a property in JSON Schema
I have a JSON object where the keys in one property are based on the value of another field. For example, if my type value is GPS, the fields object should have a lat and lng property.
{
  "type": "GPS",
  "fields": {
    "lat": 51.234,
    "lng": -1.5434
  }
}

Another scenario might be ROOM with temp and humidity properties, but there are a lot more in reality.
{
  "type": "ROOM",
  "fields": {
    "temp": 22.5,
    "humidity": 32
  }
}

The validation needs to only allow the specified fields, for example, if the type is GPS it should not allow fields.temp
Is this feasible? I am using Typescript and the NodeJS AJV package.

yes it is. now whats your real question?

you can use AJV to define a schema where the fields property changes based on the type using if then else. eg. if type is GPS, the fields must have lat and lng, and no extra fields are allowed. Similarly for ROOM it should only have temp and humidity
{
    "allOf": [
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "const": "GPS"
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "fields": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "lat": {
                                "type": "number"
                            },
                            "lng": {
                                "type": "number"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "lat",
                            "lng"
                        ],
                        "additionalProperties": false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}



if: { properties: { type: { const: "GPS" } } },
then: {
properties: {
fields: {
type: "object",
properties: { lat: { type: "number" }, lng: { type: "number" } },
required: ["lat", "lng"],
additionalProperties: false,
},
},
},
}

Did you know you can just edit your answer?  I think this JSON would be better in the answer where you can format it.

Also, the if/then/else keywords are 100% JSON Schema, not just AJV.  I would recommend Hyperjump over AJV since it represents the spec more completely and compatibly.
